# Mounting a stone for display

Tags: technique-selection, stones

I have acquired a fossil stone that I would like to display - its 1.6kg, 30cm x 12cm (15cm at its widest).
I was really after some ideas as to how to mount this - maybe perhaps on a wooden plinth but then I'm not sure how robust this would be and how to do it. I'm basically wanting for this to sit on a mantelpiece rather than hanging from a wall.
I think I would prefer to not have this damaged as it's very old and I would be worried this might crack etc. Had thought about an easel plate holder but that doesn't seem strong enough.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the shape of the stone?

Answer (score 1):

I think a wooden display shelf would be a great solution (I'm not sure if that's what you meant by 'plinth').

For the nicest presentation, I recommend you let the depth of the shelf depend on the angle in which the fossil stone can lean against the wall without any possibility of it tumbling over.
You might also want to consider a shelf with an edge for additional support, like this:

[image]
<sup>[source](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hf6f9c08bf07d4ecea85b26021691d74d5/Kitchen-Floating-Shelves-Wall-Mounted-Wooden-Rack-Decor-for-Room-Kitchen-Storage-and-Display-DIY-Hanging.jpg_q50.jpg)</sup>

Or you can use brackets to either hang a shelf from, support one, or to support the stone itself (there are many types (L, J, P, square, &c.) and options, see e.g. [here](https://www.ecosia.org/images?q=shelf%20brackets)).
This and the former solution are quite easy to make yourself, by repurposing wood for example.

The neatest solution would be a '**floating shelf**':

[image]
<sup>[source](https://www.ikea.com/eg/en/p/lack-wall-shelf-white-90282180/)</sup>

Of course, the strength (and capacity) of the wall mount depends on the fastening and the wall itself. I wouldn't suggest any of these options for drywall (although some brackets might survive for long enough with the right expanding drywall anchors, but I've no experience with that. You can of course use the studs to which the drywall is secured, like in [this video](https://youtu.be/BpS_MEHfgac)).
In brick or concrete you'll have to drill holes and use plugs, but the shelf will be sturdy.